# jquery double call due to wrapper

Tags: jquery

I have a number of jquery functions that are executed twice when wrapped with the standard $(function(){. One of these functions as shown below will execute once unwrapped, and will execute twice with the wrapper around it.

I have an ajax call that I made a few adjustments to as well. When you wrap it, it calls the new version once and the old version once. Unwrapped just calls the old version. I saw a bug about double execution due to the function being embedded in a div. Is this possible?

Working on jsfiddle demo. Will have it up shortly.

```
$(".words").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#hideme:first").attr('id', '').insertAfter($('#9999'));  
});
```

UPDATE: I was able to fix some of the calls when I found a bad event handler in a third party code. However, one still remains. I have changed the id to ensure that there isn't a conflict. It seems that there is another bad event handler somewhere. Is there any way in firebug to find the event handler to an anchor?

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a jsfiddle that causes the same problem. In my example, I put two divs, both with class "test", and nested one inside the other. Clicking the outer calls the function once, and the inner calls it twice. My guess would be the same thing is happening to you.

http://jsfiddle.net/jcolicchio/HXVcm/

Edit: this seemed to fix it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.test').click(function(e){
        alert("HI!");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});​
```

Seems like adding e.stopPropagation is what you're looking for, not preventDefault, which applies to links and submit buttons

Comment: An excellent suggestion. I changed my code. However, the problem persists and I didn't have any embedded division names.

Comment: My next thought is that somehow the function was bound to the click event twice. Try putting an alert before and after the code you pasted to us, and see how many times both alerts occur.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.stopPropagation();` to stop executing the function twice.

```
$(".words").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#hideme:first").attr('id', '').insertAfter($('#9999'));   
});
```

`event.stopPropagation();` will prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/